# locate gaps in sequential time list

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I have a list of 64,000 gps points with sequential time signatures.  I need to locate any gaps in time greater than 15 minutes.  Is there a way to do this with excel?  Here's a sample of the data.

```
16:23:58
16:23:59
16:24:00
16:24:01
16:24:02
16:24:03
16:24:04
16:24:05
16:24:06
16:24:07
16:24:08
17:55:56
17:55:57
17:55:58
17:55:59
17:56:00
17:56:01
17:56:02
17:56:03
17:56:04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will put `HERE` at the start of a gap greater than 15 minutes:

```
=IF(A2-A1>=TIME(0,15,0),"HERE","")
```

It would go into B1 and be copied down.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much.  It worked perfectly.