# Find gaps in sequentially hex numbered file names in Linux

Tags: linux, find, directory-listing

I have folders containing files with sequentially numbered file names (hexadecimal):

```
00001a08
00001a09
00001a0a
00001a0b
<---
00001a32
00001a33
```

Is there a way using linux tools to find gaps in the sequences like for example the `<---` highlighted one?

Up to now I only had the idea to export the file list to Excel and use a formula to check for the "distance" of each entry and their previous one? (See [locate gaps in sequential time list](https://superuser.com/q/1204050/201572)). The detour through Excel was a bit cumbersome if I need to check this from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using bash:

```
 i=0
 for x in * 
 do
   if (( 16#$x > 16#$i + 1 ))
   then
     echo "gap $i .. $x"
   fi
   i="$x"
 done
```

output

```
gap 0 .. 00001a08
gap 00001a0b .. 00001a32
```

if you don't want the first result start with `i=ffffffff` instead of `i=0`